# Trouble Running AlchemyAPI Natural Language Classifier APP in Bluemix

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi, nl-classifier

I've successfully deployed the `AlchemyAPI Natural Language Classifier Sample App` in `Bluemix` [here](http://natural-language-classifier-nodejs-bia810-1752.mybluemix.net).

However, when I run it I repeatedly get output:

> "Not Found Error"

no matter which question I select and ask.

Comment: you can get support asking here -- https://developer.ibm.com/answers/ or opening a ticket (https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support). Your question unfortunately does not provide enough information for someone to help

Comment: The Natural Language Classifier is not part of the AlchemyAPI, although they are both part of IBM Watson. I've submitted some new tags to get this to the attention of the right subject matter experts.

Answer (score 0):

The **not found** exception is probably because you didn't create and train a classifier.
There is a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier/get_start.shtml) that explains how to create and train a classifier.
You will need the service credentials that you can get from Bluemix.
One thing I want to clarify is that Natural Language Classifier is not part of the Alchemy apis.

---

To create a classifier you will run:

```
curl -i -u "<username>":"<password>" \
-F training_data=@<path_to_file>/weather_data_train.csv \
-F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"TutorialClassifier\"}" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers"
```

**weather_data_train.csv** is [here](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier/resources/weather_data_train.csv)

Once the classifier is trained(~10 minutes) you need to update the sample application to point to the created classifier, see this [guide](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/natural-language-classifier-nodejs#getting-started).